# If I'm just trying to show something is NP-hard (as opposed to NP-complete) does my reduction need to be completed in polynomial time?

Tags: complexity-theory

I have a problem that I believe is NP-hard. If I reduce a NP-complete problem to it in exponential time (and not polynomial time), does that prove the problem is NP-hard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hardness/completeness is always defined with respect to a specific kind of reduction.

Using exponential-time reductions doens't work at all, because that means your reduction is even more powerful than the thing you're reducing to.<sup>*</sup>
Every language except $\emptyset$ and $\Sigma^*$ is NP-hard under exponential-time reductions. To see this, let $L$ be any language except $\emptyset$ and $\Sigma^*$, and let $X$ be in NP.  We can reduce $X$ to $L$ as follows. Fix two strings $w_{\mathrm{yes}}\in L$ and $w_{\mathrm{no}}\notin L$. Now, given a string $x$, we can determine in exponential time if $x\in X$. If it is, the reduction maps $x\mapsto w_{\mathrm{yes}}$; otherwise, it maps $x\mapsto w_{\mathrm{no}}$.

<sup>*</sup> OK, technically, we don't know that EXP is more powerful than NP, but it's certainly at least as powerful, and probably more powerful.

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense. But let's say I found a reduction of time O(n^k), where k is a variable such that k <= n. What complexity class would this be?

Comment: The only way you could have $k\le n$ for all $n$ would be to have $k=0$ or $k=1$, and I don't think that's what you mean.

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain it. I have a grid with k squares. The upper bound of the size of the grid is n squares.

Comment: @cccompro then you have a grid with $O(n)$ squares?? No need for $k$ if we don’t need an tight bound—this is linear.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble It's not a tight bound because the problem is packing things into the grid (it is similar to bin packing but not exactly) and I have a reduction of time O(n^k)

Comment: @cccompro In computational complexity, there is a strong convention that $n$ represents the size of the input. So a reduction that runs in time $O(n^k)$ takes an input of length $n$ and runs for $O(n^k)$ steps for some $k$ that is independent of $n$. It's not clear to me what your $n$ and $k$ are, and the comments here aren't a good place to deal with it. I suggest you ask a new question which clearly explains the input to your reduction and its running time. I'll happily answer that (unless somebody else does first).